# Custom Routes not working in Codeigniter 3.0.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

i have a problem with my custom routes !

my routes codes works fine in CI3.0.1 but after upgrading to CI3.0.2, it just shows 404 for my custom routes !
my .htaccess is works fine and correctly, since i just uploaded app/config/constants.php file and system/ folder to my host ( as mentioned in documentation of upgrading )

does anyone know, what cause the problem ?!

url: http://www.example.net <-- Default Controller works fine 
url: http://www.example.net/admin <-- uses routes , shows 404  
url: http://www.example.net/admin/index <-- works fine O.o !

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'ctrl_main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['(:any)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1';
$route['main'] = 'ctrl_main';
$route['main/(:any)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1';
$route['main/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1/$2';
$route['main/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1/$2/$3';
$route['main/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1/$2';
$route['main/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1/$2/$3/$4';

$route['admin'] = 'ctrl_admin';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'Ctrl_admin/$1';
$route['admin/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'Ctrl_admin/$1/$2';
```

Comment: did you changedd htaccess or the apache config/setup

Comment: no, i just used htaccess which i used for CI3.0.1

Comment: excactly what changes did you made

Comment: did you follow this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_302.html also note points

Comment: exactly i made no changes ! as in upgrading docs of CI from 3.0.1 to 3.0.2 said, i just uploaded the new config/constants.php and system/ directory of new version to my host. route.php and .htaccess files are same as before

Comment: and did you make changes before upgrading system/ directory. and application/config/constants.php file

Comment: nope! .htaccess and routes.php are exactly the same as they were

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type http://www.example.net/admin, it is routed through

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1';
```

So CodeIgniter assumes there is method `admin` in `ctrl_main` controller.

Your route `$route['(:any)']` will never allow any routes bellow. Read about pecedences on routing in docs. You should keep `$route['(:any)'] = 'ctrl_main/$1';` at the end of `routes.php` file.

Comment: yeah its as you said, but i dont understand why this code is working properly in CI 301

Comment: I can't find logic in irregularity. This way I propose is one that is adviced. In first place you shouldn't leave `$route['(:any)']` as first route. You have to sort your routes by precendences according to documentation. If this solved your isssue, you can check answer as correct. Happy coding.

Comment: sure!  your suggestion worked fine. please vote up to my question ;)